# how add a new axis with differenct scale (parallel with y axis) in altair

Tags: python, altair

```
base = alt.Chart(df).encode(alt.X('monthdate(date):O'))
line = base.mark_line(color='red').encode(y = 'something:Q')
bar = base.mark_bar().encode(y = 'otherthing:Q')
(line+bar)
```

i'm trying to plot two variable in each date, problem is the scale of "something" and "otherthing" is different(one varies 1-100 other varies 1-2000000000) so i can't see changes of one of them in chart(one of them become a smooth line)
what can i do?

a  third axis parallel with y axis  with other scales is a good solution how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(line + bar).resolve_scale(y='independent')
```

More information at [Altair: Scale and Guide Resolution](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/scale_resolve.html)